# undefined index error using session on php

Tags: php, xampp, dreamweaver

I have a login.php file with a form to login.
I have a validation.php file to validate login, with this code:

```
<?php

session_start();

if(($_SESSION['user'] == "user123") && ($_SESSION['pass'] = "123"))
{

 header("Location: index.php");

}

else
{
 header("Location: login.php");
}

?>
```

And i have a index.php file, when i do the login i want go to index.php page, with this code:

```
<?php

session_start();
if(($_SESSION["user"]) and ($_SESSION["pass"]))
{
    ?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml2/DTD/xhtml2-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1993/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=u2f-5" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>geageagge</p>
<p>egeageage</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>geagaegea</p>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
else
 echo "You didnt do login";
```

But i got this error: undefined index user user, in this line: `if(($_SESSION["user"]) and ($_SESSION["pass"]))`

Anyone know what im doing wrong?

Comment: you have a mistake in your first file if condition. `if(($_SESSION['user'] == "user123") && ($_SESSION['pass'] = "123"))` use `==` not `=`

Comment: thanks, but i have the same error :/

Comment: use print_r to check whether the key "user" exists  or not.I think that could be the problem.

Comment: when i open the login.php page when i click on submit im always in the same page to login when i put correct login or wrong login, i think that is not entering in if

Answer (score 1):

1) Little mistake in `login.php` (I guess)

This 
`$_SESSION['pass'] = "123"` should be 
`$_SESSION['pass'] == "123"`

2) Check if value [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
if(isset($_SESSION["user"]) and isset($_SESSION["pass"]))
```

---

### Edit

After I saw your html form I think you have few mistakes.

in `validation.php` you have to check the value of the input, so you need to use [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) and then if they are correct put them in the session.

So your code in `validation.php` should look somet

```
<?php

session_start();

if(($_POST['user'] == "user123") && ($_POST['pass'] == "123"))
{
 $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
 $_SESSION['pass'] = $_POST['pass'];
 header("Location: index.php");

}

else
{
 header("Location: login.php");
}
```

Comment: in index.php i have this error: undefined index user. In login.php i dont have error the form appears but when i answer the textfield i click on submit and dont do nothing

Comment: Can you provide us with your login form?

Comment: <body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="validation.php">
  <p>
    <label for="user">User:</label>
    <input type="text" name="user" id="user" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="pass">Pass:</label>
    <input type="text" name="pass" id="pass" />
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Now we need `validation.php`. I'd recommend you to put your code in the answer.

Comment: thank, you now the login is working..when i put the wrong login i dont go to inde.php when i put correct login i go to index.php! but the problem now is the same in index php on this line: if(($_SESSION["user"]) and ($_SESSION["pass"]))

Comment: Replace the line with `if(isset($_SESSION["user"]) and isset($_SESSION["pass"]))` use isset as I said.

Comment: now when i do login i dont have the error but i have the message " you didnt login", but i put correct login!

Comment: in the index.php dont go to the if condition always go to else: "you didnt login", so maybe some problem here: if(isset($_SESSION["user"]) and isset($_SESSION["pass"]))

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to help you anymore. Just go ahead and read some beginner tutorials.